# TempData not showing resultview and returning null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am having trouble with stored value on TempData, Actually I am learning behavior of TempData and tried with some workable example from various sites.Here is problem : I opening my context file after some linq operation I am saving it to my variable , I used Breakpoint to inspect data,But data is not in TempData. Please  can anyone tell me where data will be stored such that I can inspect it using breakpoint of Visual studio.Below is my code

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
     ReadContext db = new ReadContext();

      var lst = (from p in db.data1
                   join f in db.data2
                   on p.ID equals f.ID
                   select new
                   {
                       Sr = p.Sr,
                       Group = p.Group,
                       ID=p.ID,

                       CompanyName = f.CompanyName
                   }).ToList()
                   .Select(x => new dataViewModel()


                   {
                       ID=x.ID,
                       Sr = x.Sr,
                       Group = x.Group,

                       CompanyName = x.CompanyName
                   });
        TempData["l1"] = lst;
        return View(lst);
    }
```

Including output as image(first beakpoint at Var) ![1]:https://i.stack.imgur.com/cysIC.jpg
Second Breakpoint at TempData ![2]:https://i.stack.imgur.com/qU79r.jpg which is showing me null value is on TempData. What I need to do to see values are visible in breakpoint.

Comment: have you stepped throuogh that line and then checked? looks like you haven't  executed that line in debugger

Comment: Have you tried TempData["l1"] = lst.ToList();?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad yes I stepped through that line but still it is  showing me value =0

Comment: @Antipod yes i tried TempData["l1"] = lst.ToList(); but not showing any tempdata value

Comment: What if you have a variable like var data = lst.ToList(); What do you have in the data variable? What if you sent the data to the view like View(data)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default TempData provider uses cookies. In order to store an object in TempData you need to serialize it first.

```
TempData["l1"] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lst); //using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

The amount of data stored in TempData should be minimized. Rather than storing entire records in TempData I would recommend just storing a list of IDs.

> Does the application use TempData only sparingly, for relatively small
>   amounts of data (up to 500 bytes)? If so, the cookie TempData provider
>   will add a small cost to each request that carries TempData. If not,
>   the session state TempData provider can be beneficial to avoid
>   round-tripping a large amount of data in each request until the
>   TempData is consumed.
>
> [Introduction to session and application state in ASP.NET Core][https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?tabs=aspnetcore2x#tempdata]

Comment: You might try storing, then retrieve a simple string in TempData to see if it works. Then we'll know if the TempData is working or if it's an issue with the List.

Comment: Also, regarding your second screenshot. That line of code has not run yet, therefore the contents of lst have not been assigned to TempData. Set your breakpoint on the next line and check it again.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var lst = (from p in db.data1
                   join f in db.data2
                   on p.ID equals f.ID
                   select new
                   {
                       Sr = p.Sr,
                       Group = p.Group,
                       ID=p.ID,

                       CompanyName = f.CompanyName
                   }).ToList()
                   .Select(x => new dataViewModel()


                   {
                       ID=x.ID,
                       Sr = x.Sr,
                       Group = x.Group,

                       CompanyName = x.CompanyName
                   }).ToList();
```

Comment: Don't just post code without an explanation of how it answers the question.